# java Json.toJson with Mockito.mock = Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class from 3rd party lib, lets call in Detail Class

In my test file, I have code like this:

```
private Details details;
...
details = mock(Details.class);
//details = new Details(); // without mock, it works no error.
...
List<Details> DetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
DetailsList.add(details);
when(myPost.getDetails()).thenReturn(DetailsList);
```

In my source code, I have

```
List<Details> details = myPost.getDetails();
details.forEach(detail -> {
JsonNode detailJson = Json.toJson(detail); // this line throw error with when I use mock in unit test
...
})
```

The issue is, if I mock my class in unit test, like `details = mock(Details.class);` then it would give me the following error on this line `Json.toJson(detail)`

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Infinite 
>   recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InterceptedInvocation["mock"]-org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor["mockHandler"]-org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler["invocationContainer"])

However, if I don't mock it, and use `details = new Details();` instead, there is no error.

The info I found online saying that this error happens because the class (eg: Detail) has circular reference. However, I don't think that is the case, because without using mock on Detail class, there is no issue at all.

This error only happens when I use `Json.toJson` with `Mockito.mock` together. Any encounters this issue before?

Comment: Does `when(myPost.getDetails()).thenReturn(new Details());` work? What is `DetailsList`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks for ur reply. i have added missing code.

Comment: why do you want to mock Details? you dont set it up in any way. Try to show us the full test method, maybe things will get clearer

Comment: If `Detail` is a *Data Transfer Object* (DTO) or *Value Object* without any (business) logic it should not be mocked. You don't mock things just because you can, you mock *dependencies* to separate your tested code from the *business logic* provided by this dependencies. DTOs are no *dependencies* in that sense.

Comment: Did you find a solution?